# Elastic search querying without Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I got tired of trying to figure out how to query my data the way i wanted using Nest - it always seems to infer the wrong url to post the search request to?

Anyway - I have put together this ugly looking code that seems to work:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = node;
                var content = new StringContent("{\"size\": 0,\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"wildcard\": {\"FlogDetail.AdditionalInfo.QueryString-filter[slug]\": \"*" + slug +  "*\"}},{\"range\": {\"@timestamp\": {\"gte\": \"now-1d/d\",\"lt\": \"now\"}}}]}},\"aggs\": {\"results\": {\"date_histogram\": {\"field\": \"@timestamp\",\"interval\": \"hour\"}}}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync(@"usage*/_search", content);
                string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JObject o = JObject.Parse(resultContent);

                return o;
            }
```

Now, before I go and make it more sane and pretty, is there any issue with querying ES like this?

My mian issue using Nest was that I couldn't see a way to query the wildcard index that you can see I am able to do with plain old C#

If anyone knows the answer to that last bit I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with querying Elasticsearch in the way that you've proposed. NEST supports querying against wildcards, single indices, multiple indices e.g.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Index("usage*")
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

sends the following request

```
POST http://localhost:9200/usage*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

NEST's convention is to map a POCO to a type within an index, and you can set up a convention for a given POCO with `DefaultMappingFor<T>(...)` on `ConnectionSettings`

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultMappingFor<MyDocument>(m => m
        .IndexName("usage*")
    );

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

There is no convention for specifying that the type name should be omitted for a given POCO however, so the call to `.AllTypes()` is still needed in the search request to search across all types in indices matching `usage*`.

Comment: Awesome  - thank you! This is *exactly* what I was looking for!